# Different class attributes with Html::nestedList methode in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, submenu, nested-lists, class-attributes

I want to build a Menu which should have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="level1" >
  <li>
    MenuItem1
  </li>
  <li>
    MenuItem2
    <ul class="level2" >
       <li>
         SubMenuItem1
       </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

and so on.
I'd like to do this with the Html::nestedList methode in CakePHP. For this I have an associative array like

```
$list = array(
  "MenuItem1",
  "MenuItem2" => array(
    "SubMenuItem1"
  )
)
```

To set the class for the ul elements in the list I can use an option array, but then every ul tag in this list has this class.

How can I have different classes for the different levels in this menu?

Comment: You could try to use the tree helperas outlined [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/) in combination with threaded data and a callback or element.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I read in the [source code](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-HtmlHelper.html#900-917) you won't be able to do that.

The only idea that comes to my mind is that you write a CSS rule to apply whatever you have defined in "list2" to the UL children of ul.level1